# I need to dispaly information in pages

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am using following code

```
<sx:div>

    <display:table id="accessLogList" name="accessLogList" requestURI="Search.action" 
          pagesize="10" defaultsort="1" >
        <c:forEach var="product" items="${ProductList}" varStatus="loop">
          <display:column property="${product.name}" title="Name" sortable="true"  
                      headerClass="sortable" />
       </c:forEach>
    </display:table>

</sx:div>
```

it does not show any thing in the browser, but in the html source file the product.name is correctly embedded as following.

```
   <display:table id="accessLogList" name="accessLogList" requestURI="Search.action" 
        pagesize="10" defaultsort="1" >

        <display:column property="Shampoo A" title="Name" sortable="true" 
        headerClass="sortable" />
```

I am need a way to show a list of products (using paging) and allow users to add them to their shopping list, should I use display:table if yes please help me to solve the issue if not what else is available to use?

Comment: <display> is not a valid HTML tag, so no wonder that you can see anything.

Comment: @reporter, its a valid Struts2 tag isn't it? whats your suggestion?

Comment: Is it the "display" tag coming from the displaytag library that you're using ?

Comment: @WiseTechi, actually not sure I found it on a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The `displaytag` table will iterate through the elements by itself, you don't have to do it yourself with `forEach`.

Given your sample and assuming `productList` (accessible in the page scope) is an iterable of entities having a `name` property that you want to display, the correct fragment would be :

```
<display:table id="productList" name="productList" requestURI="Search.action" pagesize="10" defaultsort="1" >
    <display:column property="name" title="Name" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
</display:table>
```

Comment: I ran it but same as before nothing was shown on browser and in the HTML source I just saw  <display:table id="productList" name="productList" requestURI="Search.action" pagesize="10" defaultsort="1" >
    <display:column property="name" title="Name" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
</display:table>

Comment: please note that the productList is a List and contain a list of product objects.

Comment: Yes, that's what I assumed. Can you check that you define correctly the taglib of displaytag in your page : <%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net/el" prefix="display" %>

Answer (score 0):

The code, that you found in your browser is not HTMl. It seems that `<display>` tag won't be excuted by the server. Your server does post it as plain HTML response to the browser. This is normaly a sign that the framework did not find any java classes for executing. Check your configuration that associated tag library is published correctly.